# How to syntax highlighting for ejs file in netbeans

Tags: node.js, netbeans-8

I have been working in netbeans IDE since long time and recently started coding in NodeJs but there is no highlight code for ejs file. How to rid from this problem.

Answer (score 38):

You need to configure ejs file extension with some associative file type. Steps:-

- Go to Tools -> Options
- Click on Miscellaneous Tab then Files tab
- click the "New" button
- Type your desire extension without the dot(e.g, **ejs**).
- Select the appropriate file type from the "Associated file type (MIME)" drop down box. e.g, **HTML Files(tex/html)**
- Click "OK" and you are done