# How to add syntax highlighting for .ejs files in netbeans?

Tags: express, ejs, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

[How to add syntax highlighting for .ejs files in netbeans ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3nIx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the plugin basically. You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218403/how-to-syntax-highlighting-for-ejs-file-in-netbeans).